# How to get .php file from Form Action url

Tags: php

I want to secure my forms processes files by putting them outside server root,
but i don't know how can i access them ...
that's my try

index.php

```
<form method = "post" action = "root_path/script.php?name=process_script.php"> ... </form>
```

script.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && !empty($_GET['name'])){

    $script_name = strtolower($_GET['name']);
    $process_path = 'process_path';
    $file_name = "$process_path/$script_name";

    if(file_exists($file_name)){
        //Here i don't know what i have to do to return needed process file
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: just... don't do this... I can request any file from your server that way. Even your passwords files etc...

Comment: Yes that's true, I was about make things much simpler for attackers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to run the 'process_script.php' or provide it for download so here's how to do both:

---

To include the process file into your script use either:

```
require $file_name;
```

Or:

```
include $file_name;
```

`require` throws a fatal error if the file doesn't exist, whereas include does not.

---

If you want to provide this file for download use http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php.

---

### Security consideration

However, make sure you sanitise the inputs passed to `$file_name = "$process_path/$script_name";` because as it stands an end user would be able to run / download any file on your server by simply passing different GET variables.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't pay attention to the ability of downloading files, i think i will use require instruction